# Ionic Action Sheet destructive Text

Tags: ionic-framework

I want to create an ActionSheet with Ionic => simple but I want to display the destructive Text like in the Documentation from Ionic. So that the destructive Text isn't append to the normal Buttons.

[Action Sheet Documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicActionSheet/)

Here is my ActionSheet:

```
var hideSheet = $ionicActionSheet.show({
    buttons: [
       { text: 'Facebook' },
       { text: 'Twitter' },
       { text: 'Chat' },
       { text: 'copy URL'}
    ],
    destructiveText: 'Report',
    titleText: 'Share with your friends on...',
    cancelText: 'Cancel',
    cancel: function() {
          // add cancel code..
    },
```

Here is a Image how it looks on the Tutorialpage:

[image: Tutorial-Page]

and here is how it actual looks in my app:

[image: actual app]

How can I display the destructiveText like the Cancel-text? As a 
"standalone-text"

Comment: your action sheet is ok but what is exact problem try to upload a codepen

Comment: updated the Question. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, seems like `ionActionSheet` directive is been changed..!
the gif image in documentation is not been changed..!

so, after checking the **ionActionSheet directive** in **ionic.bundle.js** . it looks like they have changed the template

```
template: '<div class="action-sheet-backdrop">' +
            '<div class="action-sheet-wrapper">' +
              '<div class="action-sheet" ng-class="{\'action-sheet-has-icons\': $actionSheetHasIcon}">' +
                '<div class="action-sheet-group action-sheet-options">' +
                  '<div class="action-sheet-title" ng-if="titleText" ng-bind-html="titleText"></div>' +
                  '<button class="button action-sheet-option" ng-click="buttonClicked($index)" ng-class="b.className" ng-repeat="b in buttons" ng-bind-html="b.text"></button>' +
                  '<button class="button destructive action-sheet-destructive" ng-if="destructiveText" ng-click="destructiveButtonClicked()" ng-bind-html="destructiveText"></button>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div class="action-sheet-group action-sheet-cancel" ng-if="cancelText">' +
                  '<button class="button" ng-click="cancel()" ng-bind-html="cancelText"></button>' +
                '</div>' +
              '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
          '</div>'
```

if we see, here `titleText`,`button` and `destructiveText` are placed under same `action-sheet-group`

where as `cancelText` is separate from other..

so..that's its..!hope this helps..!i will update if anything more i get..!

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your help! I updated the question. Maybe it's clearer now.